# Use wildcard to do fuzzy-search, with a variable

Tags: oracle, iterator, wildcard, fuzzy-search, database-cursor

I am new to Oracle programming (started coding a month ago).

I am doing a fuzzy-search, as follows:

```
WHERE SQL_text like '%VARIABLE%'
```

The problem is, VARIABLE is a cursor that iterates through a table that looks like this:

USA
UK
Japan
...

Could you please advise how to specify a variable in that WHERE clause?

I've tried the following, but it doesn't work:

```
WHERE SQL_text like '%'||VARIABLE||'%'
```

Thank you very much! I greatly appreciate everyone's input!

Comment: Please, provide the code that generates the cursor. Do you really need it or you just want to retrieve filter values from some other table?

Answer (score 0):

It works, if you use it correctly. I don't have your tables, but - I have Scott's `emp` so I'll search for jobs that contain certain substring.

Table contents:

```
SQL> select ename, job from emp order by job; 

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
SCOTT      ANALYST   --> 2 analysts
FORD       ANALYST
MILLER     CLERK     --> 4 clerks
JAMES      CLERK
SMITH      CLERK
ADAMS      CLERK
BLAKE      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
TURNER     SALESMAN
MARTIN     SALESMAN
WARD       SALESMAN
ALLEN      SALESMAN

14 rows selected.
```

Code you're looking for:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> declare
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    for cur_r in (select 'ERK' var from dual union all  --> clerks
  5                  select 'NALY'    from dual            --> analysts
  6                 )
  7    loop
  8      select count(*)
  9        into l_cnt
 10        from emp
 11        where job like '%' || cur_r.var || '%';
 12      dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.var || ' is contained in ' || l_cnt || ' row(s)');
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
ERK is contained in 4 row(s)
NALY is contained in 2 row(s)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```